# Convert dataset to a graph object

Tags: r, networking, igraph

I have a dataset for a weighted and bipartite network:

```
    A   B   C   D   P
W   0   0   0   1   0
Q   0   0   0   7   13
E   0   0   0   16  1
T   0   0   0   5   1
U   0   1   0   23  1
R   1   0   0   10  2
M   0   0   1   13  4
H   3   0   0   13  5
L   0   0   0   3   3
```

I wanted to convert to a graph object but I did not know how to do it, I have to use `graph_from_adjacency_matrix` or `graph_from_data_frame`? 
Any idea to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to start with `graph_from_incidence_matrix`. Assuming your data is in a data frame named `df1`, with column and row names as in your question:

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_incidence_matrix(df1, weighted = TRUE)

E(g)
+ 21/21 edges (vertex names):
 [1] W--D Q--D Q--P E--D E--P T--D T--P U--B U--D U--P R--A R--D R--P M--C M--D M--P H--A H--D H--P
[20] L--D L--P

E(g)$weight
 [1]  1  7 13 16  1  5  1  1 23  1  1 10  2  1 13  4  3 13  5  3  3
```

Comment: Really appreciate it and one more question how can I add row and column names to this graph? @neilfws

Comment: Take a look at the `add.names` argument to `graph_from_incidence_matrix`. By default the row and column names of the data frame are added as vertex names: `V(g)$name`.